# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^n_{-n}fdm=\int fdm$

Tags: limits, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is integrable over $[-n,n]$ for every $n \in \mathbb{R}$ and assume that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^n_{-n}fdm < \infty.$$

Proposition: $f$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$ and
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^n_{-n}fdm=\int fdm.$$

I'm having trouble with proving the integrability. Once that has been shown, I can complete the proof by applying the dominated convergence theorem and using the appropriate indicator function.

Comment: If $f=\chi_{x>0}-\chi_{x<0}$, we don't have the result.

Comment: Or even f(x)=x...

Comment: I figured something could be wrong with the hypothesis. But what if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^n_{-n}|f|dm < \infty?$$

Comment: In this case, it will work. Have you tried a proof?

Comment: Let $f_n=f \chi _{[-n,n]}$ and consider $f_n^+$ and $f_n^-$. The functions in the latter two sequences are non-negative, measurable and increase monotonically to $f^+$ and $f^-$, respectively. By the monotone convergence theorem $$\int f^+dm=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n^{+} dm< \infty$$ and likewise for the other function. Is that valid?

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption $\left(\int_{[-n,n]}f\mathrm dm\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is convergent, the result does not hold (take and odd non-integrable function).

However, if we assume that $\left(\int_{[-n,n]}|f|\mathrm dm\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is convergent, the integrability of $f$ follows from Fatou's lemma.

In the OP's argument, we have to be sure that $\left(\int_{[-n,n]}f^+\mathrm dm\right)_{n\geqslant 0}$ is convergent, but it's not *a priori* clear.